# HTML5 video (videojs) pause() & play() doesn't work?

Tags: html, video

I have a fully functional HTML5 video, it's ID is "**#html5-video-7345**".

I'm trying to control it using jQuery but I don't know how.

NOTE: I don't need an autoplay, this is just simplified version of what I need:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert('test1');
    jQuery('#html5-video-7345').player.play();
    alert('test2');
 });
```

Alerts "test1" twice.

The same happens with `jQuery('#html5-video-7345')[0].player.play()` or `jQuery('#html5-video-7345')[0].play()`.

What's wrong? How to stop() / play() HTML5 videos using jQuery/JS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't able to find videojs function reference and Google was totally misleading. Luckily I found this solution, and it works perfect:

```
jQuery('#html5-video-7345').player.play(); //wrong
jQuery('#html5-video-7345').player().play(); //correct
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the [`canplay`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-canplay) event has fired before trying to calling `.play()`:

```
jQuery('#html5-video-7345').bind("canplay", function() {
    this.play(); // Should start video
});
```

The `canplay` event is fired when the browser can start playing the video, but it doesn't guarantee that it can play the video to completion. If that doesn't suite your purposes, there are a couple of other related events that you can listen to such as [`loadeddata`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-loadeddata) and [`canplaythrough`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-canplaythrough).